# Solving trig equation $10\sin^2x + 10\sin x\cos x - \cos^2x - 2 = 0, -360 < x < 360$

Tags: trigonometry

I’m having a hard time solving this trigonometric equation:

$$10\sin^2x + 10\sin x\cos x - \cos^2x - 2 = 0, -360 < x < 360$$

I’ve tried factoring but it didn’t work. Any help will be appreciated. …

Comment: Please try to learn and use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please add your work on factoring, even if you think you hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos{x}=0$ then $\sin^2x=\frac{1}{5},$ which gives $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=\frac{1}{5},$ which is a contradiction.

Thus, $\cos{x}\neq0.$

Now, let $\tan{x}=t$.

Thus, $$10t^2+10t-1-2(1+t^2)=0$$ or
$$8t^2+10t-3=0$$ or
$$8t^2+12t-2t-3=0$$ or
$$(4t-1)(2t+3)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=2 \tan^{-1}(t)$ using a [tan half angle substitution](http://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m113/handouts/weierstrass.pdf).

Then $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2}$

The expression is now

$$ \frac{40 t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} + \frac{20 t (1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2} - \frac{(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}-2 = 0$$

$$ - \frac{ (t^2+8t-1) (3 t^2-4 t-3) }{(1+t^2)^2} =0 $$

$$ \begin{cases} 
  t^2+8 t-1 =0 & \Rightarrow & t=-4 \pm \sqrt{17} \\
  3 t^2-4 t-3 =0 & \Rightarrow & t = \frac{2}{3}\pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}
\end{cases}\\ \begin{cases} 
  x = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) & & x = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)-\pi \\
  x = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2}{3} \right) + \frac{\pi}{2} & & x = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2}{3} \right) - \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

First,
change
$10\sin^2x + 10\sin x\cos x - \cos^2x - 2 = 0
$
to
$11\sin^2x + 10\sin x\cos x =3
$.

Next,
use the double angle
formulas to make this
$3
=11(1-\cos(2x))/2 + 5\sin(2x)
=11/2-11\cos(2x)/2 + 5\sin(2x)
$
or,
setting $2x = y$,
$5/2
=11\cos(y)/2 - 5\sin(y)
$
or
$5
=11\cos(y) - 10\sin(y)
$.

The right side
is of the form
$a\cos(y)+b\sin(y)
$.
Dividing by
$c 
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
=\sqrt{221}
$
gives
$u\cos(y)+v\sin(y)
$
where
$u = 11/c, v=-10/c$.

Choose $z$ such that
$\sin(z) = u,\cos(z) = v$
by
$\tan(z) = u/v
=-11/10$
gives
$u\cos(y)+v\sin(y)
=\sin(z)\cos(y)+\cos(z)\sin(y)
=\sin(z+y)
$
so
$5
=c\sin(z+y)
$
or
$y
=\arcsin(5/c)-z
$.

Using
$\arcsin(x)
=\arctan(x/\sqrt{1-x^2})
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\arcsin(5/c)
&=\arctan((5/c)/\sqrt{1-(5/c)^2})\\
&=\arctan(5/\sqrt{c^2-25})\\
&=\arctan(5/\sqrt{196})\\
&=\arctan(5/14)\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
y
&=\arctan(5/14)-\arctan(-11/10)\\
&=\arctan(5/14)+\arctan(11/10)\\
&=\arctan(\frac{5/14+11/10}{1-(5/14)(11/10)})\\
&=\arctan(\frac{12}{5})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$x = y/2$,
$\tan(y)
=\tan(2x)
=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}
=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}
$
where
$t = \tan(x)$.

Therefore
$2t=(12/5)(1-t^2)$
or
$t^2+5t/6= 1$
or
$(t+5/12)^2
=1+(5/12)^2
=(13/12)^2
$
or
$t
=5/12 \pm 13/12
=3/2, -2/3
$.

Therefore
(whew! - 
there probably is a much easier way)
$x = \arctan(3/2)$
or
$\arctan(-2/3)
$.